# Python tkinter- Stretch a widget across two rows with .grid()

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I looked through the tkinter documentation, however I don't quite understand what they mean.
My code for a VERY simple ui (Not actually connected to anything yet) is-

```
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

Label1 = Label(root, text="Input: ")##.grid(row=0, column=0)
Label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
##Label1.configure(text="Test")
Label2 = Label(root, text="Key:   ")##.grid(row=1, column=0)
Label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
##Label(root, text="Input: ").grid(row=2, column=0)
Input_Box = Entry(root, bg="grey")
Input_Box.grid(row=0, column=1)
Key_Box = Entry(root, bg="grey")
Key_Box.grid(row=1, column=1)
##Input_Box.pack(anchor=CENTER)
def Encrypt_Button_Press():
    User_Input = Input_Box.get()
    print(User_Input)
    Encrypt_Button.configure(text="Encrypting")
def Decrypt_Button_Press():
    User_Input = Input_Box.get()
    print(User_Input)
    Decrypt_Button.configure(text="Decrypting")


Encrypt_Button = Button(text="Encrypt", command=Encrypt_Button_Press)##.grid(row=1, column=0)
Encrypt_Button.grid(row=3, column=0)
##Encrypt_Button.grid(row=1)
##Encrypt_Button.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=LEFT)

##Button_Text = "Text1"
Decrypt_Button = Button(text="Decrypt", command=Decrypt_Button_Press)##.grid(row=1, column = 1)
Decrypt_Button.grid(row=4, column = 0)

Output_Box = Text(root, height=2, width=15)
Output_Box.grid(row=3, column=1)
##Decrypt_Button.grid(row=2)
##Decrypt_Button.pack(anchor=CENTER, side=LEFT)
root.mainloop()
```

Down at the bottom of the code there is a text box called Output_Box, what I am trying to do is stretch it across rows 3 and 4, rather than expanding row 3.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Add `rowspan = 2` to your `grid()` call

Comment: For a comprehensive documentation of grid:  http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html

Answer (score 2):

What you want to do is:

```
Output_Box.grid(row=3, column=1, rowspan=2)
```